# Mocha - тестирование в окружении браузера

Tags: javascript, тестирование, mocha

Подскажите пожалуйста можно ли запустить скрипт для тестирования на библиотеке **mocha** в окружении браузера.

Мне не нужна визуальная часть! Нужно чтобы был доступ к объекту WebSocket.
Какие библиотеки для этого можно использовать?

Answer (score 0):

Библиотека **jsdom-global** подходит для решения моего вопроса.

```
before(function () {
    this.jsdom = require('jsdom-global')();
});

after(function () {
    this.jsdom();
});

describe('Тестирование ...', function () {
    it('Выполнено ...', function () {
        console.log(window);
    });
});
```

Comment: Для тех, кто зайдёт на форум в поисках ответа на этот вопрос - напишите, пожалуйста более развёрнутый ответ.